# i write 3d matrix . but why it is showed it is 2d

Tags: python, numpy

i write a 3 dimension matrix. i used .ndim to get the dimension.
but it shows it is 2D

```py
third_matrix = np.array([[23,45,56,78],[98,76,54,43],[80,79,57,35]])
print("third matrix dimension = ",third_matrix.ndim)
```

*output is :*

third matrix dimension =  2

Comment: It is 2D. There's one big list with another inside of it. What are you trying to do with 3 dimensions?

Comment: just learning.can you tell me by code where should i correction?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what a '3 dimension matrix' is?  Your array has shape (3,4).  Do you understand that?  What shape did you expect?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do though. A 3D matrix would look something like this: `[ [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[-7, -8, -9], [-10, -20, -30]] ]`, but I don't really see how the matrix you already have could be changed to 3D.

Comment: Do you mean *a list of four 3d-vectors*?

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of lists, so it is a 2D matrix. In order to make it 3D, put the numbers in lists.

i.e

```
[ [[23],[45],[56],[78]],  [[98],[76],[54],[43]],  [[80],[79],[57],[35]] ]
```

Comment: i get it.but why it is not 3d

Answer (score 0):

You also have to have in Mind, that `numpy.array()` only accepts an iterable as input, not many, maybe the confusion is there.

```
2_D_list = [[23,45,56,78],
[98,76,54,43],
[80,79,57,35]]
numpy.array(2_D_list)
```

The output is exactly the same.
Its a 2D list. THere are 3 elements in the parent list, and each of those has 4 Ints.

Comment: "only accepts an iterable as input" You passed the exact same input, and the only thing you changed was to put the list in a variable first. This is functionally identical to the code in the question.

Comment: i think i need know more what is difference between 2d and 3d.

Comment: -Eric Jin, it is true, that the code does the same, i just wanted to show that it can be stored in variable, maybe it reduced the level of complexity

Answer (score 0):

These are the dimensions

```
1_dimension = [4, 9, 4, 5]
2_dimension = [[23,45,56,78],[98,76,54,43],[80,79,57,35]]
3_dimension = [[[23],[45],[56],[78]], [[98],[76],[54],[43]], [[80],[79],[57],[35]]]
```